# Alacritty font rendering

Tags: fonts, terminal-emulator, powerline, font-rendering, alacritty

**[Initial]** I installed alacritty on Ubuntu 20.04 without a problem, by simply installing cargo and then running [this script](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ales-tsurko/cc8cb59f6d5a1aa95512e81e3dfe64ff/raw/524559dd1557de73f6e33ed0612fe747d89d633f/install-alacritty-ubuntu.sh).

**[Root Cause]** Wanting easier theme juggling, I looked up utilities for this purpose and found [this one](https://github.com/rajasegar/alacritty-themes). After installing a random theme, the script left behind a `~/.alacritty.yml` file.

**[Current issue]** Now the terminal looks like this:

[image: like this]

**[Issue description]** Fonts clearly aren't rendering anymore, the powerline prompt is also messed up. I tried running a bare `sh` session with alacritty  and the same behavior could be observed. Deleting the `.yml` did nothing. Overwriting it with `cp .config/alacritty/alacritty.yml .alacritty.yml` also did nothing.

**[Now what?]** I am curious if anyone would have any suggestion about how to fix this, my internet searches were fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

Running `alacritty -vvv` and skimming through the output, it seems that the loaded config was the one under `.config/alacritty/alacritty.yml`. Deleting that fixed the issue.

Keeping only the color-related block managed to be an okay hack in experimenting with themes, but I am open in finding out if there's any easier way in theme picking/previewing.